# Flash movies are played like in slow motion

Tags: windows-xp, browser, flash

All flash movies are played like in slow motion... I reinstalled windows but this happens again.. how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your Flash version.  The same thing has been happening with me since I upgraded it, so try an earlier version.  Of course, the best way to fix the problem is to stop everyone from distributing video content in Flash.  It is not a video player, never has been, and never will be.  It can consume at least 5x the resources of a good video player, so if you have an older computer like I do, it sometimes makes websites SO SLOW.